# Quod Libet player tray not working

Tags: 16.04, system-tray, quodlibet

Tray icon (after installing plugin to have it) doesnt work at all. Right/left click don't have any result at all. I don't really need the controllers, just opening the player will be enough. Using Kubuntu 16.04.01

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a newer version using the official PPA: https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html#ubuntu

Comment: This is the place i get it from. I got latest.

Comment: @fixxxera ok, I'll give it a try on Kubuntu and see If I can find a solution

Comment: @fixxxera I've pushed an update to the PPA. It should be available in an hour or so. I've made the package depend on gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 which is needed under KDE. You can also install it manually: "sudo apt install gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1"